# Disable android wear pending intent action confirmation

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm currently working on an app with notification which are shown on a wear device. The notification contains an action binded onto the notification card (.setContentAction(0)).

[image]

Everything is working fine, except that it shows a confirmation message everytime someone clicks on the card.

[image]

Since the card gets updated as soon as someone clicks on it, it's not necessary to show a confirmation.

I already check the official documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html#show-confirmation) if there is a way to stop the confirmation, unfortunately I didn't find a solution so far.

Edit 09.07.2015

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                    .setGroup("GROUP")
                                    .setGroupSummary(false)
                                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer_white_48dp);

ArrayList<NotificationCompat.Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();
NotificationCompat.Action control = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(icon, null, pendingTimeIntent).build();

actions.add(control);

builder.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addActions(actions).setContentAction(0).setBackground(background));

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID_WEAR, builder.build());
```

Comment: No, that's why I started a bouny.

Comment: do you have a standalone wearable application ? I recently worked on a SmartWatch app, and I didn't have this problem. Can you post some code?

Comment: It's only a notification, not a full smartwatch app. I am aware that it is possible to do it wit a smartwatch app, but its overkill for my usecase.

Comment: can you post how are you filling up the Notification object ?

Comment: Hi Blackbelt, I added the code I used back then.

Answer (score 0):

you could try modify your constructor like:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                    .setGroup("GROUP")
                                    .setGroupSummary(false)
                                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                    .setShowWhen(true)                                                                                   
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer_white_48dp);
```

Note the line:

```
.setShowWhen(true);
```

And you can modify the flag of the Intent to false:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE,
                ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,
                getString(R.string.msg_sent));
intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_WHEN, false);
startActivity(intent);
```

I don't know if it works properly, but I hope it gives you a clue.

Comment: This is not working, since NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addActions(actions) only takes actions of the type NotificationCompat.Action, which just work with a pendingintents. It's not possible to add an extra to a pending intent.

Comment: This doesn't work, since wearextender notification action pending intent set  is not the confirmation activity intent , since this notification is triggered from phone app , not from wear app

Answer (score 0):

To disable the confirmation message when a user clicks on a notification action on a Wear OS device, you can set the `NotificationCompat.Action.Builder.setShowsUserInterface(false)` flag.

```
NotificationCompat.Action control = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(icon, null, pendingTimeIntent)
.setShowsUserInterface(false)
.build();
```